# How to add Subtle Hover Effect on my website

Tags: html, css

I hope is someone here who can help me find out how should I add the Subtle Hover Effect from this [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/19/ideas-for-subtle-hover-effects/). I've tried everything, I added the .grid, I have .component imported from css. On my website I have the following HTML

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
    <h4 class="headline">Recent Work</h4>
</div>

    <div class="grid">
            <figure class="effect-romeo">
                <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                    <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                    <a href="#">View more</a>
                </figcaption>           
            </figure>
    <figure class="effect-romeo">
                <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                    <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                    <a href="#">View more</a>
                </figcaption>           
            </figure>
    <figure class="effect-romeo">
                <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Wild <span>Romeo</span></h2>
                    <p>Romeo never knows what he wants. He seemed to be very cross about something.</p>
                    <a href="#">View more</a>
                </figcaption>           
            </figure>

    </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and CSS

```
   figure.effect-romeo {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

figure.effect-romeo img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,300px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,300px);
}

figure.effect-romeo:hover img {
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

figure.effect-romeo figcaption::before,
figure.effect-romeo figcaption::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}

figure.effect-romeo:hover figcaption::before {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) rotate(45deg);
}

figure.effect-romeo:hover figcaption::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) rotate(-45deg);
}

figure.effect-romeo h2,
figure.effect-romeo p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-romeo h2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,-150%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,-150%,0);
}

figure.effect-romeo p {
    padding: 0.25em 2em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,150%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,150%,0);
}

figure.effect-romeo:hover h2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

figure.effect-romeo:hover p {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) translate3d(0,100%,0);
}
```

But the hover effect are strange, it works bad. The images are just 50 % from the original img presented on tutorial. 
Hope someone can told me what I should add or remove.

Your answers would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you paste a link to a working demo please so we can see whats going on properly?

Comment: Why don't you download source and run it???

Comment: I've tried to run it but same result.  @Jay, I can't, I don't a domain yet. Also I can't add a picture because I don't have 10 on my reputation.

Comment: I tried you code with CSSDesk: http://www.cssdesk.com/nttWL. Is this what you are seeing aswell?

Comment: Yes, @phm. Also the line from the half of the screen it's not equal on my image from my website. It's on the right of the image.